# To perform onclick action on tree component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the **tree** component in my project. Above the **tree** component I have placed an **input** component called select offering as shown in below image.

[image]

Here I need some of the actions which are available in the **select** component. My requirements are:

1)When I enter the input field then only **tree** has to display and if I leave it has to hide.

2) When I select the child element from the parent element for example, As shown in the image **Web Technologies**(Parent element) under this if I select **HTML5**(Child element). The child element as to be displayed in the input field.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-ytjqu5?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.html) link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use the (focus) event to handle the visibility

2) Use a (click) event on the items and ngModel on the input.

Code:

```
<input matInput placeholder="Select offering" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (focus)="showDropDown = true">

<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" *ngIf="showDropDown ">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding (click)="selectedItem = node.item;showDropDown = false">
          <button mat-icon-button disabled ></button>
          {{node.item}}
  </mat-tree-node>
  ....
</mat-tree>
```

I edited your code accordingly:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-2qt9rg?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.html